# Dating the Battle of Ten Kings relative to the Ramayana and Mahabharata

Tags: hindu

(cross posting from hinduism.SE. Hope this is OK)

Related to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13747/timeline-of-the-battle-of-the-ten-kings-in-the-vedas) question though much more specific: are there any clues we can glean about the historical situation of the Battle of Ten Kings relative to the Ramayana or other well known events? Maybe through genealogies etc?

Answer (score 2):

The battle of the ten kings happened in around 1400bc

**The battle of the ten kings**

> The battle took place during the middle or main Rigvedic period,[3] near the Ravi River in Punjab. It was a battle between the Puru Vedic Aryan tribal kingdoms of the Bharatas, allied with other tribes of the north west India, and the Trtsu-Bharata (Puru) king Sudas, who defeats other Vedic tribes.
> [1400bc. click on this link and look over to the right side of page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings#:%7E:text=The%20Battle%20of%20the%20Ten,the%20Ravi%20River%20in%20Punjab.)

**600 years after the arrival of Aryans**

The battle was fought between Aryans, the Puru, the vedic and other tribes.
The battle took place 600 years after the arrival of Aryans.

**Aryans arrive 2000bc**

> relating to or denoting a people speaking an Indo-European language who invaded northern India in the 2nd millennium BC, displacing the Dravidian and other aboriginal peoples.
> [Aryans 2000bc](https://www.google.com/search?q=aryan&oq=aryan&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60l3.1566j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Though Aryans are associated with Norse folk. It was not actually norse folk that the puru and vedic were fighting, but instead Iranian Persians, that were/are descended from europeans that are in turn descended from norse people that migrated south during the younger dryas/last mini ice-age between 15,000bc and 9000bc, in Northern regions.

Answer (score 1):

I found another reference apart from Steven Ian Gall's answer above: R.C. Majumdar in "The Vedic Age" places the battle around 1900 BCE based on a presumed dating of the Mahabharata in 1400 BCE.